# making sense of a for loop with an if statement in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, boolean, boolean-expression

This is a practice question to prep for an exam. We are given this code:

```
x=c(T,T,F,T,F)

for (i in 1:5){
  if(i > 1 & i < 5){
     x[i ] = x[i-1] & x[i+1] & x[i]

     print(x)
  }
}
```

and asked to predict the output. The output is:

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

and I cannot for the life of me make sense of this. Can someone please explain the logic behind the output? I have used for loops and if...else statements in other contexts but the true/false is really throwing me off. I'm assuming there are three lines out output because there are 3 values of i in the if statement. When I try to "run" the code in my head I come up with a single line of output, "TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE", because i=1 and i=5 would be unchanged, and i=2,3,4 are false because x[i-1]&x[i+1]&x[i] give false as an answer under boolean logic.

Comment: It is updating the position of 'x' in each loop i.e. when i is 2. `x[2]` is TRUE` but if you check `x[2-1] & x[2 + 1] & x[2]#
[1] FALSE` and because the TRUE gets changed to FALSE, in the subsequent operations it is reflectedd

Comment: Or for the last row of print, 4th value `x[4-1] & x[4 + 1] & x[4]#
[1] FALSE;
> x[4]
[1] TRUE`

Comment: I think the key is in the "When I try to "run" the code in my head I come up with a single line of output" part. You get a single output line for every value greater than 1 and smaller than 5. In other words you get 3 output lines (one for 2, one for 3, and one for 4), in which every time one position of x is updated. So for 2 only one position is updated. For 3, the position of 2 was updated in the previous for loop and now the third position is updated etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

When i is 1 or 5 the loop doesn't give any output at all. When i is 2, the second place in x is replaced with the value of an 'and' of positions 1 thru 3 (which is false), and then outputs the x in its current form.

Same for i equals 3 and 4, (printing x at the end of each round) with the only visible result being turning the 4th place T into F.